# Angular 7 - Send token in a post web service

Tags: angular

I´m trying to send token header in a http.post. I try this code but return in browser log:

> Access Denied

```
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Authorization": "Token " + localStorage.getItem("token")
      })
    };

      getCron() {
        console.log(httpOptions);
        return this.http.post(
          "URL", httpOptions);
      }
```

console.log return the correct token, so this isn´t the error. The error is that i don´t know how to add exactly header token in the call. So the question is: How can i add this token in the call?

Comment: Did you check whether have token in you localstorage?

Comment: Yes. I print console.log(localStorage.getItem("token")) and has the token.

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre i think your code right try `json parse` local Storage value

Comment: Doesn´t work. SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0

Comment: Tried this `"Authorization": \`Token ${JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("token") || " ") }\`` ?

Comment: Also what about other options such as `contentType, applicationType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

 var headers = new Headers();
 headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token"));
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
 this.http.post(url, options).map(...);
```

Comment: import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); error on { headers: headers }

Comment: Edited my answer. what is an error at {headers: Header}?

Comment: error: {timestamp: "2019-01-10T10:30:04.597+0000", status: 403, error: "Forbidden", message: "Access Denied", path: "URL"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for URL: 403 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 403
statusText: "OK"

Comment: This error not because of { headers: headers }. usually, 403 is for refuses to authorize

Comment: You can skip this let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); line also.

Comment: To fix this issue please check, have you added @CrossOrigin annotation in your backend service to allow requests from different origins like the one you are sending from Angular application. Also, you can check the API using Postman you can get better idea

Answer (score 3):

This is because the post() method accepts a request body as a second argument, to http options should be the third argument.

```
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Authorization": "Token " + localStorage.getItem("token")
      })
    };

      getCron() {
        console.log(httpOptions);
        return this.http.post(
          "URL", null, httpOptions); // replace the null with a body
      }
```

If you don't have any data to post, you may want to change the endpoint to a GET in stead of a POST.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token") });
```

Then call the http request using new headers:

```
this.http.get(url, { headers: this.headers }).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Here's the difference between 401 and 403: a 401 Unauthorized response should be used for missing or bad authentication, and a 403 Forbidden response should be used afterwards, when the user is authenticated but isn’t authorized to perform the requested operation on the given resource. So bisacally you are authenticated but not allowed to do some operations, please check with your server code maybe you are missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Use interceptors to append a token to every HTTP request.
Store the token in a user object and use an Auth service to retrieve it.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../service/Authentication/authentication-service.service';



@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token if available
        let currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
           request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ currentUser.token) });  
           
        }

        return next.handle(request`enter code here`);
    }
}
```